# how to get the clicked element details like textvalue or button name or id in Xcode ios application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift5, xcode12

I'm trying to get the user interaction in iOS application, For example where user clicked, which button user clicked etc. is there is any way to capture these details in Xcode swift?

Comment: Hello, suppose you have 3 buttons on the viewcontroller. make an action of all 3 buttons. When the user tap on the button then the action will call so you know which button is tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do that like this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onButtonClick(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc
func onButtonClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // you may get the detail by 'sender' object here
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

If you have multiply sender that invoke the same method, you can give them a tag for each. then you can detect which view invoke the event.

```
if sender.tag == YOUR_TAG {
    // do sth.
} else {
    // do sth. else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use tag values and tap gesture to identify the user interaction